# Display Color names Of Configurable Swatches On Product View Page 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-view, swatches

I hope someone can help,

I have Configurable Swatches working on my site, Magento 1.9.

Some of my customers are confused by the fact that the name of the colour swatch only appears when they hover over the swatch.

I would like to put the name of each colour swatch beneath the swatch.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to add this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the template of the colour swatch for the product view page in :

```
template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches.phtml
```

And in this template, you can access the label (name) of the options with :

```
$_option->label;
```

You can then display it as you like.